# "Please generate new Identifier" error when pushing to cloud services using Android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, google-cloud-platform

I successfully import the project to google cloud. I am running android studio on a Mac. But, when i try to push the project to the cloud repository i get the error:

> fatal: remote error:  Invalid authentication credentials. Please
>   generate a new identifier:
>   https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

I am lost here, Android studio, git and google cloud are all new to me.

The help link provided on the error don't mention where i should get the new credentials. Running the machine command i get the error:

> machine: no arguments accepted

Comment: Weird thing happened for me. it had this problem and i delete credentials but once i select Cancel instead of entering user/pass then I ctrl+c in version control console in android studio... and it works fine now :-??

Answer (score 20):

The first time you try to clone a repo if you put in the wrong credentials they will be cached and you will continue to get "Invalid authentication credentials" error until fixed. [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) is used behind the scenes to cache credentials for sites but it is not obvious on how to edit those credentials. Here is how to fix the cached credentials on Windows:

1. Follow the [link](https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform) to get you a password to authenticate with so you do not have to use your google account password.
2. Navigate to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager[image]
3. Click on Windows Credentials and find an entry for git:https://source.developers.google.com
   [image]
4. Click on edit and use your google account email for user name and the git password you copied in step 1 for the password and save.

You should now be able to clone your repository and git will use the stored credentials to authenticate.

Comment: +1 worked for me. interestingly gcloud init provided the first time credentials, but created my username without the email provider, so it did not "name@provider.com" but instead just "name". I had to change this there and it worked!

Comment: this is such a big help! everywhere i went i just saw linux fixes for this i was about to go back to svn. thanks! this should be more visible.

Answer (score 14):

I have faced same problem but finally solved the issue after executing the following commands. Such type of issue can arise when you mistakenly enter invalid credential at first time. So it caches the credential entered at first time.

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --system --unset credential.helper
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Comment: Solved my problem! ;]

Comment: Agreed with Hizqeel. Solving, right but not knowing why is kind of dangerous. You may introduce regression in you configuration that you will encounter month later without the possibility to link it with this thread.

Answer (score 7):

For osx on Mac...this drove me bananas! I went to Keychain > All items > deleted the entry under "GitHub - source.developers.google.com/[your repo address]" and then tried again.

You have to have gone through [this process first to ensure you have the Manual Credentials set up](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-dev/cWUjNAUIiJ0), but I'm sure you knew this already.

Answer (score 3):

As goodies4uall has said, it is an issue with cached credentials. On linux(Ubuntu), these details are cached at `/home/<user>/.gitcookies`
You can edit this file and delete the lines having incorrect user details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have previously set up your repository as described on this Cloud Source Repositories [guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories), you may want to try adding your repository as a remote. As described on this second part of the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#adding_the_repository_as_a_remote), running the credential helper script may solve your remote error:

- `git config credential.helper gcloud.sh`

Alternatively, adding a `.netrc` file may be enough to get you going as long you have the following text included in it: (more information can be found on your provided [link](https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform))

- `machine source.developers.google.com login [your email address] password [Git password]`

Lastly, make sure no `source.developers.google.com` cookies are included in your Git client by following the “Instructions for Removing Cookies” provided in your same [link](https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform).

Comment: In my case, I had .gitcookies for a different gcloud account than the one I was authenticated to (because I was trying to clone as a service account). Commenting out my personal cookies ended up fixing this. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using and/or creating a instance template, ensure you supply the correct permissions under **Identity and API access**.

Under Access scopes:
choose either
"Set access for each API" or "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs", DON'T choose "Allow default access", which gives only Read

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `gcloud auth login` command to re-authenticate to google cloud SDK.
2. Post that use your project by running your command `gcloud config set project --PROJECT-ID--`.
   This will resolve your credentials issue. It worked for me as well. Hope this helps for others as well.