# git push cloud showing invalid authentication credentials error

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I want to push an application to google cloud repository

I added the remote repository for git like this:

```
git remote add cloud  https://source.developers.google.com/p/abc/r/xxxxx
```

then I made a commit and executed `git push cloud`, but found the following error:

```
fatal: remote error:


Invalid authentication credentials.

    Please generate a new identifier:
      https://source.developers.google.com/new-password
```

Also clicking the link and verified in google can't even work.

Query:

How to push in google cloud?

Comment: ...and your programming question is what? Even assuming that this was on topic, the privciple of a [mcve] should still apply, i.e. that you provide the details how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You can’t push to a repo you don’t have permission for.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt to reproduce, follow the steps on "https://source.cloud.google.com" when adding a new repository using the Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: Search [mcve] for "in the question itself". A link isn't considered sufficient, @PeetBrits.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt okay, but that is pretty much it. The only thing that comes before `remote add` and `push`, as per the updated question, is to install Google Cloud SDK and then initialise it, e.g. `gcloud init && git config --global credential.https://source.developers.google.com.helper gcloud.cmd`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have defined the [right credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#adding_the_repository_as_a_remote)

```
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh

# Or, on Windows:

git config credential.helper gcloud.cmd
```

That way, you would not use the wrong credentials which might have been cached in the [current credential manager, as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367469/6309).

And make sure you do own the remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

After confirming my credentials in the [current credential manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367469/371917) (thanks to [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49484240/371917) for the link), what worked for me was to first check out the empty repository in a different folder

```
gcloud source repos clone <repo> --project=<project>
```

which will give a warning, because the repository is empty

```
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

and then I added my code to this folder, commit it locally on git, and then try to `git push` again

```
cd <folder>
# git add <...>
# git commit <...>
git push -u origin master
```

**EDIT**: This answer assumes you already installed and initialised [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk)